# Center divs within another div using all available space

Tags: html, css

I would like to center divs using all the available space in a parent div.
Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p8DGH/) jsfiddle. With this method, the divs will float at the center irrespective of what the parent's width is, creating so much whitespace at far ends of the row.
[image]
But I want to have 1st and last yellow boxes to stick to left and right edges respectively and center ones should float in the middle.
When I resize the parent div, child divs should adjust themselves automatically.
Is it possible?
Another Question, which is a continuation, can I remove the "row" divs from markup and still achieve the same result?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div>Row 1 1</div>
    <div>Row 1 2</div>
    <div>Row 1 3</div>
    <div>Row 1 4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div>Row 2 1</div>
    <div>Row 2 2</div>
    <div>Row 2 3</div>
    <div>Row 2 4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container{
    border: 1px solid #2aF1E2;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row{
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #2351E2;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.row div{
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #eac300;  
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: initial;
}
```

Comment: Im sure it impossible with css.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want the items to be a fixed size and justified (equally distribute the space between them)?  Must the elements be 4 per row no matter what?

Comment: @cimmanon yes. I want 'em 4 per row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking is called **Flexbox**. Anyways, if you can afford for a wrapper, I guess you can make use of it.

But with Pure CSS you can do this way:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="wrap left"><div>Row 1 1</div></div>
    <div class="wrap mid"><div>Row 1 2</div></div>
    <div class="wrap mid"><div>Row 1 3</div></div>
    <div class="wrap right"><div>Row 1 4</div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="wrap left"><div>Row 2 1</div></div>
    <div class="wrap mid"><div>Row 2 2</div></div>
    <div class="wrap mid"><div>Row 2 3</div></div>
    <div class="wrap right"><div>Row 2 4</div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row div div{
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #eac300;  
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: initial;
}

.wrap {width: 25%; float: left;}
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/p8DGH/3/

Comment: Thank you for keeping it simple.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving it with the markup you have now, you can get exactly what you want with Flexbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/4CXuy/3/

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid #2aF1E2;
}

.row {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #2351E2;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -moz-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-flex-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row div {
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #eac300;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

If you want to remove the `.row` elements, then you have to use percentages to ensure your items are lined up into exactly 4 columns.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: This effect is precisely what I am looking for but as you pointed out in that link there are compatibility issues. Its not supported in IE 8 and 9, so I cant use it. Thank you for the new concept. Looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is ideal but:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container{
    border: 1px solid #2aF1E2;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row{
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #2351E2;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.row div{
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #eac300;  
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: initial;
}

.row div:first-child {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.row div:last-child {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px; 
}
```

And here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CXuy/)

Update:

```
.row div{
    margin: 10px 5% 10px 5%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #eac300;  
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: initial;
}

.row div:first-child {
    float: left;
}

.row div:last-child {
    float: right;   
}
```

It still doesn't work 100%, for instance when the screen size is too small some weirdness happens, but I'd kind of expect that from using percents.

Comment: I thought of that, but 2nd & 3rd elements are unequally closer now. I want them all equally separated.

Comment: I've updated it to include equally distanced elements in the rows.